# how to upload the datas to webserver from android mobile

Tags: android, upload, webserver

how to upload the datas to  webserver from android mobile.Please provide coding

Comment: What datas? What have you done so far?

Comment: @Select0r i want to upload rawimages to the webserver

Comment: Make API calls from your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this compiles:

```
HttpPut request = new HttpPut(<uri>);
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(<your data>));
HttpResponse response = HttpClient.execute(httpPut);
```

You might want to use the HttpPost instead of HttpPut and also specify the content type on the request.